# Airport transfer in Sanya

Tags: china, airport-transfer, syx

I am flying into SYX airport and staying at a nearby beach hotel.  What would you recommend is the best way of getting to the hotel?  Are cabs reliable there or do I need to arrange for some sort of car service?

Comment: SYX = Sanya Phoenix International Airport, in China

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's the *best* option, but on http://wikitravel.org/en/Sanya it mentions that the new train station in Sanya is far from downtown, *approximately as far as the airport*, and that a taxi to Dadong Bay (大东海), the most popular tourist area - you didn't mention what area you're staying in - there are 20km long beaches so a bit vague) is approximately ¥25-30.

So if that's roughly the same distance, that's probably about what you'd expect to pay by taxi, plus (potentially) an airport charge.  A public bus for the same route is ¥1, so then that would be a more economical option from the airport two - Bus number 8 goes from the airport to Dadong Bay.

Another option is just to contact the hotel, they'll have been asked the question dozens of times and may have a simple option for you - maybe even a pickup if you're lucky ;)